# How to filter Data on the basis of id or uuid by Rest API?

Tags: services, polls

I am using `Drupal 8` I have installed the poll module.
I created a view with `REST` export enabled. Now when I get the data by this `url`

```
http://localhost/poll/rest/polling
```

I am getting all the data of polls like this

```
[{"question":"which is best city","choice_target_id":"Delhi, Mumbai, Chennai","id":"1","choice_target_id_1":["1","2","3"],"uuid":"b0ef150c-bf05-4a25-8ae9-b6864539c080"},{"question":"Where do you work?","choice_target_id":"Flat, Hotel, Factory, Shop","id":"2","choice_target_id_1":["4","5","6","7"],"uuid":"b2145904-fe8b-4ef6-82fa-f069c2e29f3b"}]
```

But when I get the data on the basis of `id` or `uuid` by this `url`

```
http://localhost/poll/rest/polling?id=1
```

then I am still getting all the data without getting filtered as per the `id`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven’t set up any exposed filters or you’re using the wrong filter id on them.

Comment: yes its working now

Comment: please add this as answer so i can mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven’t set up any exposed filters or you’re using the wrong filter id on them. Views needs exposed filters on it by which to limit a query by.